# How to set up a level 2 s function with no direct feedthrough?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink model being compiled to an executable through Embedded Coder (RTW) and have an SFunction that I know has no connection between the input and output so would like to turn off direct feedthrough on its input port. I could in fact make two SFunctions to replace it, one with an input, one with an output, the only complication is the external system I am addressing does its two-way communication in a single function call.

We currently use the Legacy Code Tool to compile all of our SFunctions, but this I have read and verified forces all inputs to be direct feedthrough whether they are or not (with no explanation of why.) I have had a look as the SFunction Builder block, however it makes no reference to direct feedthrough on inputs. I have also looked at the msfuntmpl_basic.m template  builder script however it seems to be limited to inputs and outputs with primitive data types (via the DatatypeID.)

Answer (score 3):

Your question asks about integrating C code into an S-Function, but then you say that you're looking at *msfuntmpl_basic.m* which is the m-code template.  You should be looking at the C template: *sfuntmpl_basic.c*.

Within it, look at line 75, which uses the macro `ssSetInputPortDirectFeedThrough` to set the feedthrough characteristics of each port, which is the only way to do it.

Since the Legacy Code Tool explicitly doesn't generate code that uses that macro, you are going to have to either write your own S-Function that does, or edit the auto generated code so that it does.

Comment: Good catch, I am only familiar with SFunctions written in C++ and am not aware of the whole landscape of methods for generating SFunctions.